# Figma to webflow - turning elements into vectors problem

Tags: figma, webflow

I'm trying to transfer design form figma to webflow. Current design has "empty diamonds" which is basically a component of a instance/child of parent component.

The content which is linked to empty diamonds is for example a button, text link etc, example:
[image]

So, when I try to copy that section to webflow (using the official plugin), it shows me an error that I can't copy "empty purple diamonds layers" and that I should use ctr+alt+b to detach instance, which I did, however in that case when i finally copy the section again - it shows vector in webflow instead of all the elements inside, so I can't edit or change it at all.

[image]

Any help regards this please, how can i copy design from figma to webflow, keeping all the elements/style and not creating images/vectors for static content like buttons/text etc?

I have limited experience with this two softwares, so can't really find a solution even though I tried searching a lot of online resources.

Thanks in advance!